# Deciphering a checksum/CRC

Tags: crc, infrared

I'm trying to figure out an error-check on the following data streams. The data comes from a commercial remote control for programming electric radiator heaters.

I have extensively researched most IR protocols (RC5, NEC etc), and from what I can tell it doesn't fit any. I can't confirm that it isn't IrDA, however.

The hardware I am using is a standard Vishay IR 38kHz receiver connected up to an old PC running WinLIRC, so I can see the raw pulse/space train, and have confirmed through various tests/adjustments the basic parameters in the config (such as time stamp which has a resolution down to seconds), that the data comes out the IR as 10-bit, one start bit, 8-bit data byte, and a stop-bit. Then I have inverted the data bytes, bit-swapped MSB-LSB to get me to a point which stacks up with the programming schedule.

My one sticking point is the last byte which I believe is the error-check, I know this because I have set up a test rig to send the data with a different error check and the heater doesn't accept it, and with a correct value as recorded is accepted.

Below is the data stream, followed by 2 more iterations, but with the time stamp advancing by 1 second in each case. I can see some mathematical similarities between the error-checks but I have tried all 8-bit CRC/checksum XOR, added, subtracted, etc decoding methods and also used reveng which hasn't yielded an answer.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

1ST ROUND OF DATA

BINARY      HEX DECIMAL     NOTES

11111111        FF  255
00000000        0   0
00001111        F   15
10110011        B3  179
01001100        4C  76
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000000        0   0
00000000        0   0
00000011        3   3
00000010        2   2       HOURS
00010010        12  18      MINUTES
00000000        0   0       SECONDS
01101011        6B  107     CRC CHECK?

2ND ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000001        1   1       SECONDS
00110101        35  53      CRC CHECK?

3RD ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000010        2   2       SECONDS
11010111        D7  215     CRC CHECK?

4th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000011        3   3       SECONDS
10001001        89  137     CRC CHECK?

5th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000100        4   4       SECONDS
00001010        A   10      CRC CHECK?

6th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000101        5   5       SECONDS
01010100        54  84      CRC CHECK?

7TH ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP MINUTES: -

00011000        18  24      MINUTES
00001101        D   13      SECONDS
01110001        71  113     CRC CHECK?

8TH ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP MINUTES: -

00011011        1B  27      MINUTES
00111011        3B  59      SECONDS
01000111        47  71      CRC CHECK?

Comment: Need more data. Please provide at least ten samples. If you can get some for different length messages, that would be useful as well.

Comment: Hi, here is some more data, I've included the same above for ease:-

Comment: 4th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000011  3 3  SECONDS
10001001  89 137  CRC CHECK?

5th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000100  4 4  SECONDS
00001010  A 10  CRC CHECK?

6th ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP SECONDS: -

00000101  5 5  SECONDS
01010100  54 84  CRC CHECK?

Comment: 7TH ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP MINUTES: -

00011000  18 24  MINUTES
00001101  D 13  SECONDS
01110001  71 113  CRC CHECK?

8TH ROUND OF DATA SAME AS 1ST ROUND UPTO THE TIME STAMP MINUTES: -

00011011  1B 27  MINUTES
00111011  3B 59  SECONDS
01000111  47 71  CRC CHECK?

Comment: not sure how to add a bigger comment, so I've broken the data up, and also the formatting is wrong now....perhaps I should start another post?

Comment: Instead of comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

CRC RevEng finds a solution to the original problem set readily.  This is a Bash command line for compactness:-

```
reveng -w 8 -s ff000fb34c00000003000000000003000000000003000000000003000000\
00000300000000000300000000000300000302\
{12006b,120135,1202d7,120389,12040a,120554,180d71,1b3b47}
```

which returns:-

```
width=8  poly=0x31  init=0xa5  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0x00  check=0x67  residue=0x00  name=(none)
```

As all the streams are the same length, CRC RevEng cannot compute both Init and Xorout.  `xorout=0x00` is a guess which forces `init=0xa5` so as to correctly compute the streams in the problem set.  Streams of length other than 52 bytes will need both parameters, and finding one will give you the means to calculate them.

`poly=0x31` appears only once in the Catalogue under `CRC-8/MAXIM`, which is also reflected but has `init=0x00`; if this is indeed the algorithm in use, then `init=0xa5` is an image of bytes fed into the algorithm that shouldn't be (i.e. the first *n* characters would not be fed into `CRC-8/MAXIM`); unfortunately I couldn't find any prefix of the data streams that equated to an initial value of `0xa5`.

If you require code to calculate these CRCs, other packages are available that will convert the Rocksoft™ model output by CRC RevEng into C, for instance [pycrc](https://pycrc.org/) or Mark Adler's [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you thank you!!!
You've nailed it!  Absolutely brilliant!
I tried again in revenge but still couldn't get anything, even copying your example. So I tried it on this website:-

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

including the last byte, with the poly and init you found and bingo!

My data stream is always the same amount, 52 bytes.

Again, many thanks to all for helping me with the formatting etc, and of course the answer!

AaronT.